# Importing XML in a string array - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm using this function to get the data of the xml file to a string array

```
 private void ReadXml(string Dictionary, char letter)
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(Dictionary);
        string[] dictionary=new string[2];
        int i=0;
        IEnumerable<XElement> de = from el in xml.Descendants(letter.ToString())
                                   select el;
        foreach (XElement el in de)
        {
            dictionary[i++] = el.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

But the array that is produced has all the contents of the xml tag I specify merged in its first line.

For example the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode"?>
<Animals>
  <A>Ant</A>
  <B>
    <word>Boa</word>
    <word>Bear</word>
  </B>
</Animals>
```

and with `xml.Descendants("B")` produces `dictionary[0]=BoaBear` and `dictionary[1]=NULL`

So how can I make it so every word gets in a separate array cell?

Thank you in adnance.

Comment: Your XML is poorly designed. You should use multiple `<Word>` tags in all cases.

Comment: You're right, I used this "word1, word2" because I thought that I was the tag that had to be different. Thanks for the advice I will change it right away :)

Comment: You should use `<word>` tags in `<A>` as well, even though there is only one word.  Uniformly-structured data  is much easier to work with.

Comment: You shouldn't re-parse the dictionary every time you call the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the elements inside the `<B>` tag by calling `Elements()`.

For example:

```
foreach(var word in xml.Root.Element("B").Elements())
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? where should i call el.Elements?

Comment: Sorry; `de.Elements()`.  In the `foreach`.  I'll add a ciorrect example.

Comment: I used it that way and I got `dictionary[0]=<word>Boa</word>` and `dictionary[1]=<word>Bear</word>`. But I think we are in the right direction :)

Comment: I found what the problem was! I forgot to place .Value inside the foreach loop. Now it works! Thanks a lot for your help! :)