# Windows Phone with XML file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm try populate a "ListPicker" from xml document.
If the xml have only one TAG "Produto", the ListPicker display the other attributes correctly. But if have more one TAG "Produto", the error is "There are multiple root elements. Line 7, position 2.".

How should I write the code for display all TAGs "Produto"?

XML:

```
<produto>
<codigo>1</codigo>
<descricao>Janela</descricao>
<valor>100.00</valor>
</produto>

<produto>
<codigo>2</codigo>
<descricao>Porta</descricao>
<valor>120.00</valor>
</produto>

<produto>
<codigo>3</codigo>
<descricao>Alambrado</descricao>
<valor>80.00</valor>
</produto>
```

Code:

```
  private void locChoice(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    


        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string filePath = "im.xml";

        if (store.FileExists(filePath))
        {

            try
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(store.OpenFile("im.xml", FileMode.Open)); ;
               ProdutoLpk.ItemsSource = from query in doc.Descendants("produto") select query.Value;
              //  string fileData;
               // using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                //   new IsolatedStorageFileStream("it.xml", FileMode.Open, store))
               // {
                  //  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                 //  {
                     //   fileData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                  //  }
               // }

               // this.ProdutoLpk.ItemsSource = fileData.Split(';');
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        ProdutoLpk.Open();
        Debug.WriteLine(ProdutoLpk);

    }

    private void Button_Enviar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        String dados = "\nProduto: " + ProdutoLpk.SelectedItem + "\nQuantidade: " + Qtd.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(dados);

        lista.Text = Qtd.Text + " " + ProdutoLpk.SelectedItem;



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggest that the problem is in your XML instead of C# code to parse the XML. Valid XML can only have single outer most tag (root element).

Try to fix your XML by wrapping it within single root element, for example :

```
<produtos>
   <produto>
      <codigo>1</codigo>
      <descricao>Janela</descricao>
      <valor>100.00</valor>
   </produto>
   <produto>
      <codigo>2</codigo>
      <descricao>Porta</descricao>
      <valor>120.00</valor>
   </produto>
   <produto>
      <codigo>3</codigo>
      <descricao>Alambrado</descricao>
      <valor>80.00</valor>
   </produto>
</produtos>
```

Comment: This solution helped me in parts. After the change, the "ListPicker" understand all products as a single product. Can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the `elements` inside the `xml` to get the tags.

Eg:

```
foreach(var word in xml.Root.Element("produto").Elements());
```

For more you could refer these which are in detail:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a88dea86-ded6-4149-a57f-b586b53940be/get-elements-tags-from-xml-file-using-c?forum=xmlandnetfx

[Importing XML in a string array - Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914726/)

Hope it helps!